# jQuery.ajax - Updating a table cell with new value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good evening. The code below is intended to update a couple of table cells with a new quantity and new checked date. However, it only updates the first row in the table. Any help appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var res = $(this).serialize();

      var req = $.ajax({ 
      url: '/stock/update',
      type: 'POST',
      data: res,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) { 
        //console.log(response);
        $('#qty').text(response.qty_new);
        $('#date').text(response.date);
        }

      });

    });
});
```

Here is the HTML as requested:

```
<table>
    <th>Part</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Date Checked</th>
    <th>New Quantity</th>
    <th>Update</th>

    % for row in stock:
    <tr>
        <td id='part'>{{row['part']}}</td>
        <td id='location'>{{row['location']}}</td>
        <td id='qty'>{{row['qty']}}</td>
        <td id='date'>{{row['date']}}</td>
        <form>
            <input type='hidden' name='part' value="{{row['part']}}">
            <input type='hidden' name='location' value="{{row['location']}}">
            <td><input type='number' name='qty_new' style='width: 4em;'></td>
            <td><button id='update_qty'>Save</button></td>
        </form>
    </tr> 
    % end

</table>
```

Comment: `$('#qty')` will select a single element with the attribute `id="qty"`. If you have multiple elements with that ID, then that's not valid HTML, so JavaScript will not recognise the duplicate ones. IDs must be unique - that's the whole point of an ID, after all! You're probably better off using a class, which can be applied to multiple elements. Do you want to update all the cells in a particular column with the same value? or should they all have different values taken from your data? It's not totally clear.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I have many rows with columns for 'product', 'qty', 'date_checked'. And an input for 'new_qty' which should update the 'qty' column. It should only apply to that one <tr> for which the button applied.

Comment: It would really help if you could show a relevant bit of the HTML to give it some context. It should be possible to locate the particular cell based on its proximity to the button but the exact solution will depend on the HTML structure of the table row.

Comment: Just added it. Thanks.

Comment: IDs must be unique. Refer to: <td id='qty'....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the cells should have classes instead of IDs because there are duplicates.

```
<td class='part'>{{row['part']}}</td>
<td class='location'>{{row['location']}}</td>
<td class='qty'>{{row['qty']}}</td>
<td class='date'>{{row['date']}}</td>
<form>
    <input type='hidden' name='part' value="{{row['part']}}">
    <input type='hidden' name='location' value="{{row['location']}}">
    <td><input type='number' name='qty_new' style='width: 4em;'></td>
    <td><button class='update_qty'>Save</button></td>
</form>
```

Next, you'll need a way to select these based on the form that's being submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var res = $form.serialize();

    var req = $.ajax({ 
      url: '/stock/update',
      type: 'POST',
      data: res,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) { 
        $form.siblings('.qty').text(response.qty_new);
        $form.siblings('.date').text(response.date);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

`$(this)` gets the jQuery-equivalent current scope of `this`, which is the form. Then the form's siblings are searched for the correct classes and the elements are modified.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks Adam.